# How to delete a directory that is being used in another process?

Tags: c#, process

I have been working on a large code that uses file streams to create log files. I want to delete a directory that contains those log files but it is giving me an error :"... is being used by another process.". I have made sure that I closed the file stream but the problem is still persisting.

How do I track down a process that uses the directory and close it? (Aside from tracking down the process in the large code base)

Any Idea or lead would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look into `using` statements for the `StreamReaders`. The `Reader` will still be open (presumably) and locking the file, thus the directory it's in. If the `reader` is discarded, you should be able to delete the directory.

Comment: I would recommend 'process explorer'

Comment: That's a great idea @JayGould. I have never used **using** like that so I never thought of it.

Comment: @glant, process explorer seems pretty helpful but I would not know what process I would be looking for in the many processes existing .

Comment: what happens when you are searching for the log file directory does it not highlight the process for you??

Comment: @glant, I am afraid not.

Comment: hmm that's weird I was hopping when you launch: process explorer > Find > Find Handle Or Dll > search for the folder name. It would have listed all the processes that are currently have it open and selecting by Type: DLL would show its process Id and highlight it on Process window